# add resolution to the Game View in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello guys I need add these resolution devices to the resolution menu in fame view in unity I add image for my problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moqMX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a resolution by pressing the plus icon at the bottom of the list.

[image: Here]

Comment: thanks JLum but I ask about add it automatically. I remember way to do that but I don't remember it?

Comment: In that case I believe it depends what platform you are set to in Build Settings. Try going File -> Build Settings and changing to iOS.

Comment: I dint that but I don't see it in the menu I don't know what the problem?

Comment: There are more resolutions when you select `Android` as target platform.